# German equivalents of "give X a run for their money"

Tags: english-to-german

In conversation, I said jokingly:

> His insistence on only ordering espresso is, well, how should I put it? It's enough to **give** even the most one-track coffee aficionado **a run for their money**...

Here I wanted to hyperbolically express the idea of:

> The way he single-mindedly orders espresso drinks every time, he may well be **evenly matched with** even the most avid of coffee drinkers, if not put them to shame.

The following came to mind as its German equivalent, but I think it's closer to "put X to shame".

> Mit seiner hartnäckigen Angewohnheit, ausschließlich Espresso zu bestellen, **stellt** er selbst die borniertesten Kaffeeliebhaber **in den Schatten**.

How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in German?

Comment: Your example with **in den Schatten stellen** is correct. I wonder if you used the English phrase *give a run for their money* idiomatically though. My dictionary says it means *jemandem/einander nichts schenken* in the meaning of a fierce competition. *Die beiden Favoriten schenkten einander nichts.*

Comment: Another typical phrase which comes to mind is *einander nichts geben*, which strictly speaking means the same as *einander nichts schenken*, but it's used on competitions on silly things.

Comment: @Janka Yes, this is a less-known usage example of "give X a run for their money”. The meanings found in dictionary entries might centre round *competition* contexts, just as you said, though.

Comment: @Janka I just happened to find a similar post : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33856/%c3%89quivalent-de-to-give-someone-a-run-for-their-money My usage is close to the *car* example mentioned there: "*The speed of my car is not to be sneezed at, compared to that of yours*"  === "*His extreme fondness for espresso is not to be sneezed at, compared to that shown by even the most avid of coffee drinkers*"

Comment: *not to be sneezed at* → *nicht zu verachten*. Maybe also interesting to you: *die Nase rümpfen* == *verachten* → *to turn up one's nose at sth.*

Comment: "Give someone a run for their money" could be closely mirrored with "jmd auf seine Kosten kommen lassen" to include the reference to money. In that sense I'm not sure your second rewording is identical in meaning, and neither is the German translation. I'd venture to say that you said "Es ist genug um selbst den borniertesten Kaffee-Liebhaber auf seine Kosten kommen zu lassen". Whether that was your intent is up for debate...

Answer (score 2):

If you mean doing something better than others that are already good at it, "jemanden alt aussehen lassen" is an informal way of saying this.

Comment: Hi. How about the colloquial "ausstechen"?

Comment: "Ausstechen" has a connotation of competition and often implies competing when competition is inappropriate.